# use subform filter and orderby parameters for a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, subform

I need to create a query to return the same records shown in a subform inside a opened form.
So I have based the query on the same recordsource of the subform; then, i have set the query `filter` and orderby properties with `[forms]![myformname]![subformcontrolname].[form].[filter]` and `[forms]![myformname]![subformcontrolname].[form].[orderby]`.
However, the query always returns all the records in recordsource as if filter and orderby were empty. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn the filter on?

```
Me.Filter = "Country = 'USA'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Check out msdn for more information regarding filters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194672.aspx

Comment: Why should I write a script? I have created a query, and set its properties from the gui. My aim is to escape to write code lines!

Comment: I think the filter needs to be turned on. If you can make sure the user turns the filter on for you you do not need code. You can turn on filter with one of the ribbon buttons. Does it work with a filter turned on?